# Find the MediaCodec supported video encoding resolutions under Jelly Bean MR2

Tags: android, resolution, encode, android-mediacodec, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Is there any way to get the [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#q=MediaCodec) video encoding supported resolutions under Jelly Bean MR2?

For lollipop we can use the new [getVideoCapabilities()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#getVideoCapabilities()) method to find out all the supported video resolutions. But for lower API levels couldn't find a way in the [MediaCodec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#q=MediaCodec) API.

I'm aware of the [CamcorderProfile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html) class available since API 8 which can give some hints of what the hardware **might support**, but to use the camcorder profiles to resolve the encoder video resolutions seems to be a guess game without consistency which could fail easily on many devices.

Answer (score 0):

If it's listed [in the CDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082938/which-video-encoders-are-guaranteed-to-be-supported-by-android-mediacodec-api/32084391#32084391) then you can assume it.  If not, you have to try and see if it works.

The `screenrecord` tool uses a retry-on-error scheme to deal with cases where the video encoder can't record at the display resolution, because there was no way to query for it back then.

Comment: screenrecord ,  Where is this the source code? I need it very much! 
I use mediacodec to record video but the video color is not right on some devices.

Comment: I don't think it will be all that useful, but it's here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/lollipop-mr1-release/cmds/screenrecord/

Comment: I have fix the video color issue, I changed the video encoding size to 720*1280(previous size:320*568), the color turned right. But I wonder that Do all phones above api-level 18 have the camera preview size 1280*720 or above?

Comment: "try and see if it works" ? Isn't there any way to find which resolutions are supported?